# Probability of P(A,B|C)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I just want to double check that this is true. Google doesn't cooperate well with equations.

P(A,B|C) = P(A|B,C)P(B|C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, because

$$
\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}\frac{P(B,C)}{P(C)}
$$